# How do you create a gitignore file in pycharm? (windows)

Tags: python, django, git, github, pycharm

[What i could find relating to git settings on pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ53m.png)

Comment: did you tried "touch .gitignore"..if this is not working try "ni .gitignore" or make a file ".gitignore" on your root directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First install the ignore plugin:

[image: PyCharm ignore plugin]

Then right-click the project root directory: `New` > `.ignore File` > `.gitignore`

[image: create a .gitignore file in PyCharm]

If you want to simply create a .gitignore file in PyCharm, go to the PyCharm terminal and type: `echo "" > .gitignore`. Then open the .gitignore file, delete the double quotes, and update however you'd like.

Comment: tysm, late reply but this looks great!

Answer (score 2):

In the `Project` tool window, select one or more files you wish to be ignored, then right click on the selection, then `Git` > `Add to .gitignore` > `Add to .gitignore`. If the `.gitignore` file does not exist, you will be asked for confirmation to create it.

Answer (score -1):

Create a file with name `.gitignore` in the root directory of your project. Add all the files which you want git to ignore while versioning, in it.